# Alternatives to get Session object in Page.PreInit event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to access Session object in PreInit event to get some values stored in user session. I found that I can create a class and inherit it from

```
public class UserTheme : System.Web.UI.Page, IRequiresSessionState
```

And use this class in PreInit event. I'm trying to figure out if there are any potential problems I can face in future with this implementation?

Is there any better alternatives to access Session object in PreInit event?

Comment: Does it work for you now?

Comment: Checked in my real application and Session object still null..

Comment: Well that sounds like a potential problem. :)